# Angular component not showing on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, angular-material, internet-explorer-11

I've written an Angular 4 Material 2 app, everything's workin fine in chrome, but on Internet Explorer the page is empty. I've added a `<h1>` to index.html which shows up, but adding one to my *content.component.html* does not work, even the code of the whole component is not added to the DOM.

*index.html* (`<h1>Test</h1>` shows up in IE):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ITEM Projekte</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

*app.component.html* (`<h1>Test</h1>` does not show up in IE):

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<md-card>

  <md-card-title>ITEM Projekt anlegen</md-card-title>

  <md-card-subtitle>PROJEKTDATEN</md-card-subtitle>
  <md-card-content>
    <div style="width: 100%; ">
      <md-input-container *ngFor="let item of projektdaten" style="margin-right: 15px; display: inline-block; ">
        <label style="width: 120px; display: block;">{{item.identifier}}:</label><input mdInput name={{item.identifier}} style="width: 150px; " (keyup)="setProjectData(item, $event.target.value)">
      </md-input-container>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <md-radio-group>
        <md-radio-button value="1" style="margin-right: 30px; ">Neubau</md-radio-button>
        <md-radio-button value="2">Umbau</md-radio-button>
      </md-radio-group>
    </div>

  </md-card-content>

  <md-card-subtitle>MATERIALKOSTEN</md-card-subtitle>
  <md-card-content>
    <md-input-container><label>Test</label><input mdInput></md-input-container>
  </md-card-content>

  <md-card-subtitle>PERSONALKOSTEN</md-card-subtitle>
  <md-card-content>

  </md-card-content>

</md-card>
```

Btw: In Edge everythings also working just fine, but I need it working in IE ...
Please let me know if you need any additional code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you receive an error in the console?

Comment: Have you imported pollyfils?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136792/angular-4-0-0-app-built-by-angular-cli-1-0-0-not-working-in-ie11

Comment: @Christian Yes, in the file `polyfills.bundle.js` it says something like _Acceptance triggered and not intercepted_. It is working now, thank you

Comment: So what was the problem? pollyfils?

Comment: I've added the solution down below, thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4128).

Just remove comments below this line in *polyfills.ts*:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
```

Comment: Hi. In my case all the lines below above comment is already in un-commented  state. Still I see blank page with with no console error with my app-component to be empty. Any Idea. I have to add es7 imports for that ?