# Angular 4 app is not working on first load in microsoft edge and ie11

Tags: angular, cross-browser, angular2-routing

I have been working on an angular 4 app. It is working fine on Mozilla and chrome but when we access it on the Microsoft edge browser, on the first load, it is not working and there is no error in the console. But when I refresh the page then it works fine. I don't understand the problem. If anybody knows about this please let me know.

I have used the following dependencies in my app:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^6.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "9.3.0",
    "angular-calendar": "0.19.0",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^1.2.0",
    "angular-sortablejs": "^2.0.6",
    "angular-tree-component": "3.8.0",
    "chart.js": "2.6.0",
    "ckeditor": "4.6.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.9.1",
    "dragula": "3.7.2",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "intl": "1.2.4",
    "jquery": "2.2.4",
    "jqvmap": "^1.5.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.0.2",
    "leaflet-map": "0.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.15.0",
    "ng-sidebar": "^6.0.0",
    "ng2-ace-editor": "^0.2.3",
    "ng2-archwizard": "^1.7.0",
    "ng2-breadcrumb": "0.5.14",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.9",
    "ng2-dnd": "^4.2.0",
    "ng2-drag-drop": "^2.5.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "1.5.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.2.1",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^3.0.1",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.6.1",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0",
    "ng2-tree": "^2.0.0-alpha.10",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "ng2modules-easypiechart": "^0.0.4",
    "ngx-mydatepicker": "2.0.12",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^1.3.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^5.3.0",
    "ngx-tour-ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.6",
    "normalize.css": "^5.0.0",
    "nouislider": "^10.0.0",
    "nvd3": "^1.8.5",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^0.6.16",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.3",
    "quill": "^1.2.3",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "screenfull": "^3.2.2",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "skycons": "^1.0.0",
    "sortablejs": "^1.6.0",
    "summernote": "^0.8.4",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "widgster": "0.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
}
```

and I have the following dev-dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/d3": "^3.5.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.52",
    "@types/jquery ": "3.2.0",
    "@types/node": "7.0.8",
    "@types/nvd3": "^1.8.33",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.3",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.6",
    "tslint": "5.4.3",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
}
```

Comment: what is the error in console

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136792/angular-4-0-0-app-built-by-angular-cli-1-0-0-not-working-in-ie11

Comment: Read this docs: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4.0.0 App built by angular-cli 1.0.0 not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136792/angular-4-0-0-app-built-by-angular-cli-1-0-0-not-working-in-ie11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your tsConfigfile it should be  like below..

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
 "module": "commonjs",
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 "sourceMap": true,
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "removeComments": false,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "types": [],
  "lib": [ "es2015", "es2017", "dom" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
 "node_modules"
],
"compileOnSave": true
}
```

i faced this issue long back but it worked for me when i added alternate lib in tsconfig. so i might help you also

Comment: There were couple of things I need to adjust like install angular animations and intl. Thanks @Natarajan