# Unable to open Angular 4 application on Safari 8.0 getting error "Unexpected token '>' "

Tags: angularjs, typescript, safari

We are facing issue  to  open  our Angular 4 application on Yosemite Mac OS. It's giving error:

```
unexpected token '>'
```

As I understand some features of ES6 (Arrow/fat functions) are not compatible with Safari below version 10.0.

Is there any solution or work around for this?

Comment: Refer this link it might help you as i faced such issue with IE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231999/angular-4-app-is-not-working-on-first-load-in-microsoft-edge-and-ie11/46232284#46232284

Comment: @vinod If my answer worked, you could accept it as correct or give some feedback to help others that may encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you said, Safari browser prior to v10.0 does not support Arrow functions. [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility)

What you can try is at your tsconfig.json set `"target": "es5"` which will create ES5 compatible code (no arrow functions).

Comment: Thanks for your reply I changed target as es5 but it didn't work for me  
I am facing same issue for IE 11 and Safari 8.0

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a plunker? Also when using 'Developer Tools' is it possible you still see your ES6 code (with arrow functions)? That would mean that es5 target for some reason is not working.